# Laravel Event w/ Javascript

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel event set up to broadcast data to the client each time a user posts a comment and then I use javascript to append that data in the view. My issue is that if user1 posts a comment to user2's profile, I only want to append that data to user2's profile and not all profiles in general. So, in my event broadcast I pass through the ID of the profile the post was posted to (i.e. user2's ID).

Then I'm thinking I can do something like...

```
@if ($user->id === $id)
    // Display appended data
@else
@endif
```

My problem is that I'm unsure how to properly check those two ID's. The $user->id references that profile's ID and then the $id is the profile ID sent through by the posted message. But I can't compare the two since the $id comes back through as a JSON object.

Should I just put the @if like this? If so, what's the correct syntax?

```
<script>
    var pusher = new Pusher('03fe3c261638a67dbce5');
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('newMessage');
    channel.bind('Yeayurdev\\Events\\UserHasPostedMessage', function(data) {

        @if ($user->id === $id)
            // Display appended data
        @else
        @endif
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to handle the pusher event in the client using javascript. . When you load the page create a dom element (a div usually) that has the users id as its id attribute. When you get the pusher message you can easily target the right div and append the message payload

Comment: That's pretty clever. I'll do that. Another thought I had was creating a user-specific channel to broadcast on. I'm thinking that's less ideal than a simple DOM traversing to match the id's. Thanks!

Comment: Pusher is awesome I have used it a few times so can't claim I just came up with it. User specific channels can be double helpful particularly for presence testing but that is another story

Comment: Alright, well I just got it working properly with your suggestion. I always get stuck with reconciling front-end and back-end and how to get those talking with each other. I'll post your solution as an answer...or feel free to post yourself and I can check it. Thanks again!